# How can generator get input noise z?

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

Hi I'm looking this GAN implementation code. [code here](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/PyTorch-GAN/blob/36d3c77e5ff20ebe0aeefd322326a134a279b93e/implementations/gan/gan.py)

My question is generator class has no input parameter when defining class Generator(#38 from the link)
But when training, generator gets input z(#141 from the link).
I looked into the nn.Module class which is parent of class Generator but I can't find input parameter for noise z. Can anyone help?

```
class Generator(nn.Module):    #38
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

        def block(in_feat, out_feat, normalize=True):
            layers = [nn.Linear(in_feat, out_feat)]
            if normalize:
                layers.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(out_feat, 0.8))
            layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True))
            return layers

        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            *block(opt.latent_dim, 128, normalize=False),
            *block(128, 256),
            *block(256, 512),
            *block(512, 1024),
            nn.Linear(1024, int(np.prod(img_shape))),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, z):
        img = self.model(z)
        img = img.view(img.size(0), *img_shape)
        return img
```

```
generator = Generator()    #88
```

```
gen_imgs = generator(z)    #141
```

I tried looking for nn.Module, variable() in pytorch docs and still can't get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider every quoted line (38, 88 and 141):

- On line 38 is a definition of class, by putting `nn.Module` in brackets it's declaring inheritance of `class Generator` from [class nn.Module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) (which is common way to define your own neural network).
- On line 88 instance of class Generator is created -- for parameters it needs all what's inside brackets of `__init__` (line 39), besides `self`,  that's why brackets on line 88 is empty.
- And on line 141 there is a calling of `genearator`, behavior here defined by method `forward` (line 58) and there is one parameter to be passed --  `z`.

Again, line 88 creates an instance, line 141 calls `forward` method of an instance.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don't understand the answer.
Are you saying generator(z) == generator.forward(z)?

Comment: yes, this equallity does indeed holds

Comment: Oh I've never seen this before. Are there more examples written this way? meaning accessing class method without "."? or what keyword should I search with? Thanks again!

Comment: There is a lot of methods like that, for example when doing `my_array[i]`  it's actually `__getitem__` method of `my_array` who's been called, and `generator(z)` actually calling `__call__` method, so all magic of `forward` is in overriding it.